# Discord.py custom statuses animation

Tags: python, discord.py

I have started experimenting with Discordbots in python, and a friend of mine taught me that you can customize the game activity manually with your Bot. So here is my Question:
If you type in the activity1, is there a way to add to activity2 and they swap each second in an infinite loop?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have it changing just not every fast, lots of popular bots actually have a changing status, but you probably can't make requests that fast (plus it could be against TOS).

Update:
I just tested this using the following code, it ran 5 times before stopping (probably rate limited)

```
@client.command()
async def statusLoop(ctx):
    for i in range(100):
        time.sleep(1)
        await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=(str(random.choice(list(range(900)))))))
```

Comment: Well, thank you for spending your time on my request, quite sad that this isnt working, but not much of a problem ether, because it is just a nice little detail xD

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `tasks.loop`

Below is the code:

```
from discord.ext import tasks
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Online")
    bot.statuses = cycle(['Activity 1', 'Activity 2'])
    change_status.start()
@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def change_status():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=next(bot.statuses)))
```